# Sharepoint 2013 - OData Endpoint against External List - Supply Input Parameters

Tags: bdc, odata

I have an external list in SharePoint 2013 that uses a filter (called `idcode`, say).

I can supply the filter value in the "Modify View" UI of the site and it works as expected, but my ultimate aim is to use the OData endpoint.

I'm using filters because the data set contains ~250,000 rows, so using the standard OData filtering mechanisms is inappropriate.

So, given the URL of

```
mysite/myweb/_api/Web/Lists(guid'[some-guid-here]')/Items
```

Is it possible to append something to the end of that URL to supply the `idcode` filter value?

EDIT - I know I can use $filter against OData, that doesn't help, because the BCS parameter is pre-filtering the results.  What I'm looking to do is pass the value of the Input Parameter defined on the BCS model via the URL.

Answer (score 1):

For filtering you can use `$filter`

Supported operations are explained in below image

[image]